# What is the correct Xpath for this element?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, xpath

[image: this is the HTML code for the element]

I need to get the text inside the element and I am using `Inner HTML`, in `Java Selenium`  but all the `xpaths` and `css selectors` written by me, are wrong, can you help me to get the right one please? Also it turn out, that the element is within a frame, how can i assess an element in a frame?

[image: this is the element]

```
  WebElement Element = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/span"));

            System.out.println(Element.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

this is the way that should help me to get the text

Comment: Is this a table? Can you share the whole DOM of this table? Tables require filtering and the understanding of the whole table's DOM.

Comment: this is not a  table, but a number for uninstall rate for some certain app, i will post the photo of the element asap

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath `"//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/span"` that you wrote is unstable due to the `/div/div[2]` part. When using a chain of `div` or indexed `div`, if something changes in the DOM  in that area, your element will not be found anymore. The xpath below are more specific to the element that you are looking for.

- `//div[contains(@class, 'layout-row')]/span`
- `//div[@id='container']/div[contains(@class, 'layout-row')]/span`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried your versions, nothing works, and it turned out, that this element is within a frame, may be that changes the situation?

Comment: Try to switch to that frame first. This post offers more details on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no/20181195

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
#container div.layout-row span
```